# Directory listing shown rather than view when http request is made in laravel 5.3

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel-5

I new to laravel and currently building an `application`. Now in the application I want to get to the `admin index page` via `via this route: /admin` but I end up

here:
`MyApp.app/admin/`

> this shows the directory content for admin folder

rather than `MyApp.app/admin`

> which should give me a view in the browser

.

I have added an `htaccess` file with the following code in it,

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

But it changes nothing.

Here is my `route` code:

```
Route::get('admin', ['as'=>'posts.home', 'uses' => 'AdminPostsController@home']);
```

And my controller code:

```
public function home(){
        //
        return view('admin.index');
    }
```

Please note: I initial used a simple code such as:

> Rout::get('/admin', function(){ return view('admin.index'});

But I still got the same problem, but accessing the views via `route resource` works fine. Perhaps there's a `standard way` of accessing views in `laravel 5.3'.

This app is on my linux computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am 99% sure the problem is that in your project you have a directory in your public directory that is named 'admin'. If you do, this almost certainly causes the problem, because Laravel finds the public dir and does not continue on to look for an endpoint under the same path in your routes.

Now, assuming that this really is your problem, what you have to do is either somehow change the directory structure, or change the name of your route.

#### First solution

Move directory `public/admin` to `public/assets/admin`

#### Second solution

Rename:

```php
Route::get('admin', ['as'=>'posts.home', 'uses' => 'AdminPostsController@home']);
```

to

```php
Route::get('administration', ['as'=>'posts.home', 'uses' => 'AdminPostsController@home']);
```

Please let me know if that was your problem :)

Comment: your a god. I would never had guessed that this was the problem. Thanks and +1 for the excellent explanation.

Comment: @udoyen Happy to be able to help mate :)